# Mod menu 'convert to wiki' description is incorrect for answers

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, community-wiki, wording

When you click 'convert to wiki' from the mod menu, the following text is shown:

> Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion.  **This affects the question and all answers.**

The sentence in bold is correct if you're converting a *question* to wiki, which affects all of the answers as well.  However, the same text is shown if you're converting an *answer* to wiki, even though converting an answer to wiki doesn't affect any other posts.

I think this is most likely because 'convert to wiki' was originally only available on questions, and when it was added to the mod menu for answers as well, the text was incorrectly reused.

To confirm this behavior, I created a test question on ell.meta with two answers, and I used 'convert to wiki' on one of the answers.  The other answer and the question were unaffected, as I expected.

This text confused a fellow moderator today.  He thought 'convert to wiki' on an answer would also affect the question and the other answers, so he didn't even try using the feature.  He knows how it works now, but I think it might be worth fixing to avoid confusing other moderators in the future.