# Mod menu for Community Wiki answer thinks it's a question

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, community-wiki, wording

When opening the mod menu for a Community Wiki answer, one of the options is

> remove wiki from this **question**

(emphasis mine). Can that be corrected?

[image: A community wiki answer showing a list of moderator actions available. This includes "Remove wiki from this question" (circled)]

Comment: Related: [Mod menu 'convert to wiki' description is incorrect for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309095/mod-menu-convert-to-wiki-description-is-incorrect-for-answers).