# Improve wording of Community Wiki tooltip while editing a question

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, community-wiki, wording, tooltips

When editing a question as a ♦ moderator, you have the option to make it Community Wiki. However, as a reverse of [Mod menu for Community Wiki answer thinks it's a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396879/295232), the tooltip thinks it's an answer:

> Marking an answer community wiki encourages others to edit it by lowering the reputation barrier required to edit. However, you will not gain any upvote reputation from it. This cannot be undone.

Better would be:

> Marking a question community wiki encourages others to edit it by lowering the reputation barrier required to edit. However, the author will not gain any upvote reputation from it.

[image]